# Help with py2exe error

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

I'm trying to compile to an exe my script of python, but I'm getting an error that I'm not know how to resolve...

my script include this libraries

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom
import time
import win32com.client
```

and the py2exe script is

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': dict(bundle_files=1, optimize=1)},
    console = ["login.macro.py"],
    zipfile = None,
    )
```

and I'm getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.macro.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "win32com\__init__.pyo", line 5, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading win32api.pyd
```

How can I solve it?

I've just compiled another script and went everything ok

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe the "." in the name of the script causes the problem.  Try login_macro.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `bundle_files=3` :

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2009-June/009227.html