# Bundling a standalone exe

Tags: python, selenium, py2exe

So, I've been trying to make a `Standalone EXE` for a very long time. Now that I installed python 32 bit, I gave `py2exe` a try, to use its `bundle_files` option to make an exe for my project [comic-dl](https://github.com/Xonshiz/comic-dl).

Since comic-dl is somewhat based like youtube-dl (Even the friggin' name), so after I couldn't get my own setup.p file to work properly, I copied [youtube-dls' setup.py file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rg3/youtube-dl/master/setup.py) and then I modified it to make it work for my project.

[Here is my modification](http://pastebin.com/qL8fWDC2). And then I run these commands :

`python setup.py install`
`python setup.py py2exe`

Everything goes fine and I get one `comic-dl.exe` (~6 MB). But, when I execute it, I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "comic-dl.py", line 4, in <module>

  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module

  File "honcho.pyo", line 12, in <module>

  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module

  File "sites\mangafox.pyo", line 13, in <module>

  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module

  File "selenium\webdriver\__init__.pyo", line 18, in <module>

  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module

  File "selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.pyo", line 39, in <module>

  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module

  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.pyo", line 25, in <module>

  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module

  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.pyo", line 40, in <module>

  File "pkgutil.pyo", line 591, in get_data

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js'
```

I checked for the `getAttribute.js` file in selenium's folder and the file is there. I even copied selenium's folder in the project itself, still no change.

Then I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089677/help-with-py2exe-error) and this doesn't make sense because not everything is bundled in option 3 and option 2 seemed same for me when I changed the option and executed the setup commands.

What can be done to get a standalone exe in this case?

Comment: Instead of using the complex py2exe, use the simple 1 stop shop called nuitka. It can build exe and Linux executable for you with one command. Also, it can bundle it without anyone figuring out it's actually python. (No need for sfx)

Comment: I've tried it with no luck. Got anything that I can use?

Comment: Cx_freeze is a good project. It's just that you have to pack a directory if you want to make it portable. A quick search can give you tons of tutorials on how to use it

Comment: I need 1 exe. cx_freeze is what I'm already using. py2exe will give me a standalone portable 1 exe out of the whole project. That's what I'm looking at.

Comment: to be honest, the last option is to use Cython. Convert your python code into C, and then compile that into an exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this problem too. Here's the way I solved it:

1. Goto `C:\Python27\selenium\webdriver\remote\` [Directory may be different if selenium is installed in other directories. The essence is to find the files]. There are `getAttribute.js` and `IsDisplayed.js` files. Copy them.
2. In you distribution `dist` folder, there's a `library.zip` file. Unzip it or open it in Windows default viewer.
3. Goto `selenium\webdriver\remote\` and paste files copied in step 1.
4. If you unzip the `library.zip`, zip it and replace the original.

It works with me. Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. Hope can help you!

## step 1: modify file webelement.py

```
# customized code to resolve resources's path problem when executing py2exe executables
import sys
frozen = getattr(sys, 'frozen', '')
if not frozen:
    getAttribute_js = pkgutil.get_data(__package__, 'getAttribute.js').decode('utf8')
    isDisplayed_js = pkgutil.get_data(__package__, 'isDisplayed.js').decode('utf8')
else:
    approot = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    getAttribute_js = open(os.path.join(approot, 'getAttribute.js'), 'rb').read().decode('utf8')
    isDisplayed_js = open(os.path.join(approot, 'isDisplayed.js'), 'rb').read().decode('utf8')
```

note: In my environment, this file is located in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote.

## step 2: In your setup.py for py2exe, include needed file into your data file. e.g.

```
data_files = [(r'.', glob(r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\getAttribute.js')),
    (r'.', glob(r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\isDisplayed.js'))]
```

Then you should get your exe working. I have tested this in windows 7, 32 bit system. python 2.7, with selenium 3.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have to set the executable in the relative path for it to reach the hard-coded file location.

Alternatively I would recommend you use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), which in best case doesn't need any configuration and can get you a working executable straight away in one command.

Comment: I already tried Pyinstaller. But, for some reason, pyinstaller doesn't include my modules and hence the exe doesn't seem to work.

Comment: nope, having the same issue with pyinstaller drove me to here

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

- C:\Python27\selenium\webdriver\remote\  There are getAttribute.js and IsDisplayed.js files. Copy them.

  - paste them into dist\selenium\webdriver\remote NOT into the zip file.
  - run .exe
  - profit